# How to alias a tag in Git?

Tags: git, shell, aliases, subcommand

I have a Git command alias to checkout the latest tag from a repository:

`~/.gitconfig`:

```
checkout-latest = !git checkout $(git describe --tags `git rev-list --tags --max-count=1`)
```

So I can use it in properly tagged repositories like this:

```
$ git checkout-latest
```

I have command aliases for the checkout command:

`~/.gitconfig`:

```
co = checkout
```

The `checkout-latest` does not work with the command aliases for checkout:

```
$ git co-latest
git: 'co-latest' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
```

How can I configure Git so that I can use latest as a tag alias that points to the programmatically determined latest tag? I would like to use it like this:

```
$ git checkout latest
```

and

```
$ git co latest
```

Note that there is **no dash between the subcommand and the tag** in my desired variants.

Comment: If you want `co-latest` to work just add it: `co-latest = !git checkout-latest`. I don't think you can do what you want without maintaining an actual tag `latest`.

Comment: Yes, that would work. But I want to neither maintain a `latest` tag in every repo nor mix up the syntax of subcommands and tags.

Comment: I don't understand that "mix up" comment but yeah maintaining a `latest` tag was not a recommendation just a comment that I don't know how else you could do it.

Comment: `co-latest` is a subcommand to `git`, while `git checkout latest` would be a command, subcommand and tag alias. I think it is ugly to have something that refers to a tag on the subcommand level.

Comment: I see. I think that's an arbitrary distinction you've drawn and one that severely limits what you can do with aliases but that's not my call. I don't believe you can do what you want here (not unless you wrap `git` itself in a shell function and do dispatch based on the subcommand and "tag/ref" arguments.

Comment: If it can't be done with Git, posting a wrapper script would be a valid answer.

Answer (score 2):

The only solution to this sort of thing I can think of is a `git` shell function that does "dispatch" based on arguments.

Something like this:

```
git() {
    if [ "$1" != checkout ] || [ "$#" -ne 2 ]; then
        git "$@"
        return
    fi

    local lastrev lasttag

    case $2 in
        :latest)
            lastrev=$(git rev-list --tags --max-count=1)
            set -- checkout "$(git describe --tags "$lastrev")"
        ;;
    esac

    git "$@"
}
```

The tag aliases need to be invalid as normal refs to be safe for hence the use of `check-ref-format`.

This construct allows for arbitrary tag "aliases" to be added via the case statement.

This function is *very* limited in terms of what arguments can be used if you want to use the tag "alias". Specifically you cannot pass any. The command *must* be `git checkout <alias>`. Parsing all valid `git checkout` combinations is simply too hard to bother with for this now (though it could probably be done).

Answer (score 2):

Git can already alias tags in the sense that you can make a new tag which points to the same commit as another tag.

What you seem to want is a macro alias; for Git to recognize a special word like `latest` and dynamically substitute that with a tag.

Since that probably isn't going to happen without modifying Git, you can make the shell do it, and interpolate via `$(...)` command substitution:

```
git checkout $(latest)
```

`latest` is just a shell script or function that dynamically computes the tag and prints it on its standard output.

Another idea is to just have an actual `latest` tag installed as an alias in the repo. When a new change is tagged, `latest` is pushed forward to that (via `git tag -F`).  Such tagging is a non-fast-forward change, of course, so the upstream repo has to allow that.

Answer (score 0):

Git aliases cannot reference other aliases.

You can accomplish this with another layer of indirection, however:

```
co-latest = !git checkout-latest "$@"
```

Comment: While interesting, this does not answer my question. I do not want to create more subommand aliases. I want to get rid of the one I have and get even better functionality with an alias on the tag level.